# How to get number of items within a category in wagtail/django?

Tags: django, wagtail

On my website page, I am trying to display the number of posts within each category on the html component. Here is an example of what I want to do below.

[image: Html component displaying number of item in each category]

I already added category names on the html component. The value next to the category names are just random number used as placeholder. I have been struggling to get the value for the number of posts within each category. I really dont know what queryset im suppose to use.

Here are my code.

**blog.py**

```py
class BlogPage(Page):
    def get_context(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context(request, *args, **kwargs)
        category_slug = request.GET.get('category', None)
        blogposts = PostPage.objects.live().public().order_by('-first_published_at')
        if category_slug == None:
            context['blogposts'] = blogposts
        else:
            context['blogposts'] = blogposts.filter(categories__slug__contains=category_slug)
            context['category_slug'] = category_slug
        context['categories'] = BlogCategory.objects.all() # category object
        return context


class PostPage(Page):
    date = models.DateField(verbose_name="Post date")
    categories = ParentalManyToManyField("blog.BlogCategory", blank=True)
    body = RichTextField(blank=False)
    main_image = models.ForeignKey(
        'wagtailimages.Image', 
        null=True,
        blank=False,
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL, 
        related_name='+')

    content_panels = Page.content_panels + [
        FieldPanel('date'),
        FieldPanel('categories', widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple),
        ImageChooserPanel('main_image'),
        FieldPanel('body', classname="full"),
    ]

@register_snippet
class BlogCategory(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    slug = models.SlugField(
        verbose_name="slug",
        allow_unicode=True,
        max_length=255,
        help_text='A slug that identify post by category.'
    )

    panels = [
        FieldPanel('name'),
        FieldPanel('slug'),
    ]

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

**blog_page.html**

```html
<ul class="cat-list">
 {% for cat in categories %}
   <li>
     <a href="?category={{cat.slug}}" class="d-flex">
       <p>{{cat.name}}</p>
       <p>{{cat.count}}</p> <!-- My attempt in trying to get the number -->
     </a>
   </li>
 {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Django's `annotate` method to add calculated values to a queryset:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/aggregation/

In this case, your `categories` query will become:

```
from django.db.models import Count

class BlogPage(Page):
    def get_context(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        # ...
        context['categories'] = BlogCategory.objects.annotate(num_posts=Count('postpage'))
```

This will allow you to refer to `{{cat.num_posts}}` in the template.

Comment: Thanks alot for the solution, I really appreciate the help. I tried using `annotate` method but I did something like this `BlogCategory.objects.annotate(num_posts=Count('slug'))`. I thought I was only limited to selecting the available fields within BlogCategory model. Where did 'postpage' argument come from. Is there a way I can find more available argument for BlogCategory model?

Comment: 'postpage' comes from the `ParentalManyToManyField` you defined on PostPage - when you set up a relation between objects, Django will add an accessor for following that relation in reverse as well. More details here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/queries/#related-objects